# Div placing 100% height

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Currently I'm having troubles getting my layout working cross-browser. In the attached image you are able to see a preview.

```
height: 100%;
```

Some information:

- div #Header

  - Width: 100%
  - height: variable
- div #Sidebar (overflow-y)

  - Width: 300px
  - height: 100% minus header + footer heights
- div #frameHeader

  - Width: 100% minus sidebar width (300px)
  - height: 100% minus header + footer heights
- iframe #iframe (overflow-y)

  - Width: 100% minus sidebar width (300px)
  - height: 100% minus header + footer + frameheader height
- div #Sticky Footer (sticky to bottom ofcourse)

  - Width: 100%
  - height: variable

I've spend countless hours trying to get this to work, I'm thinking someone should have faced this problem before? I'm hoping someone is able to give me a working cross-browser example!

Current code: http://jsfiddle.net/s6wVw/ (ugly css but I think you get the point ;))

Attachment (preview) can be found below

[preview  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BazoN.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the question? Creating cross-browser code is not trivial.

Comment: Well I can't find a way to get the #Sidebar 100% height WITHIN the header and footer

Answer (score 2):

In your question you keep making false statements and contradicting yourself (e.g. you're talking about a *sticky footer* but you also imply that the page doesn't scroll - as heights of all elements sum to 100%). However, I'll try to help you none-the-less.

For the reason stated above, I've made the following **assumptions**:

1. You want the dimensions of the main areas (header, footer, sidebar, frame header, frame body) to always sum to 100%
2. You don't want the browser to scroll
3. You want scrolling in the side bar and frame body if the content overflows

The above would lead to a poor site design because if the browser/window size were to be <= `300px` wide then you wouldn't be able to see any of the frame etc.. Similarly, if the `browser/window height <= foot height + head height` then you wouldn't see any of the `sidebar`, `frame head`, or `frame body`.

That being said, here is an example using `jQuery`, `html`, and `css`.

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
    color:#fff;
}
#head{
    width:100%;
    background:#aaa;
}
#body{
    width:100%;
}
    #sidebar{
        display:inline-block;
        width:300px; height:100%;
        background:#111;
        vertical-align:top;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    #frame{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        height:100%;
    }
        #fhead{
            width:100%;
            background:#333;
        }
        #fbody{
            width:100%;
            background:#777;
            overflow:scroll;
        }
#foot{
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#aaa;
}
h1{margin:0; padding:10px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
function setSizes(){
        var docWidth = $(window).width();
        var docHeight = $(window).height();
        var headHeight = $('#head').height();
        var footHeight = $('#foot').height();
        var bodyHeight = docHeight - headHeight - footHeight;
        var fHeadHeight = $('#fhead').height();

        $('#body').css({
            height: bodyHeight
        })
        $('#sidebar').css({
            height: bodyHeight
        })
        $('#frame').css({
            width: docWidth - 300
        })
        $('#fbody').css({
            height: bodyHeight - fHeadHeight
        })

        $('#foot').css({
            "margin-top": -footHeight
        })
    }
$(function(){
    setSizes();

    var doit;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setSizes();
        setSizes();
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="head"><h1>Head Section</h1><br><br><br><br></div>
<div id="body">
    <div id="sidebar"><h1>Side Bar</h1>
    </div><div id="frame">
        <div id="fhead"><h1>Frame Head</h1><br><br></div>
        <div id="fbody"><h1>Frame Body</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="foot">
    <h1>Foot Section</h1><br>
</div>
```

**NOTES**

1. You can put whatever content you like inside of the following divs: `#head`, `#sidebar`, `#fhead`, `#fbody`, `#foot`
2. The `jQuery` runs the `setSizes();` function twice on window resize. This is to account for any scrollbars that may impact the available width/height
3. You may need to set additional `overflow` rules to other elements depending on what content you place in the `divs`